# Adding some filed query where some parameter inherit on parent orm laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm

**Hi, regard to you all guys...**

i have somethink to ask, i want to adding some field on select query orm laravel where query param inherit from id parent table (one to many)...

maybe like this :

- tb_lelang, columns : id, name
- tb_lelangitem, columns : id, product_id, lelang_id
- tb_bid, column : id, lelangitem_id, user_id, price
- tb_user, column : id, name

lets try, i want to add some field (addSelect) on data lelangitem like : select price from bid where bid.lelangitem_id=id and user_id=2, where my orm start from tb_lelang

how the orm which i have to code (i use laravel v.8)?

i have done this think by looping on getting data before and add the field manually, but maybe its have better code out there

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After defining the relations on the respective models you could use a nested query like this:

```
Lelang::with('lelangitem', function($query) {
  $query->with('bid', function($query1) {
    $query1->where('user_id', '=', 2);
  });
})->get();
```

Comment: thank for the answer guys, but I'm sorry, what i want is adding some new field on lelangitem result data, so in results of lelangitem data become : lelangitem->latest_price_user (new field from select sub query), which on bid data have too bid data too (lelangitem->bid), you have some idea? sorry for my english not good 

Comment: @caco you can include custom data in the select query like: $query->selectRaw("name" AS `full_name`') or use laravels transform method or map method.